# How to fix 'numpy.ndarray' error while making training data-set using CountVectorizer?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I am making a text classifier on the data I have. On the basis of some observations I need to identify the target variable. I started with bag of words and tf/idf approach.

I have made the classifier with "one" feature, but when I am trying to incorporate more "features" say 7 to predict the label, the Count Vectorizer throws error for fit_transform.
Following is the code

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer    
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

bow = CountVectorizer()
# working fine for one feature
#observation = df_all_null_removed['Observation'].values
# selecting feature set of 7 variables
observation = df_all_null_removed[features].values

train_obs, test_obs,y_train, y_test =train_test_split(observation,
                               df_all_null_removed['HazardType'],                                                       
                               test_size=0.12,
                               random_state=42)
bow_matrix = bow.fit_transform(observation) # throws error - screen shot attached.
```

I think its because "observation" is a 2 dimensional numpy array of shape [8150,7] and we need to convert it into 8150 rows of 1 column array.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-140-d75b27bd1080> in <module>()
----> 1 bow_matrix = bow.fit_transform(observation)
      2 print("The vocabulary of the bow",len(bow.vocabulary_))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
    867 
    868         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
--> 869                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
    870 
    871         if self.binary:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
    790         for doc in raw_documents:
    791             feature_counter = {}
--> 792             for feature in analyze(doc):
    793                 try:
    794                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in <lambda>(doc)
    264 
    265             return lambda doc: self._word_ngrams(
--> 266                 tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
    267 
    268         else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in <lambda>(x)
    230 
    231         if self.lowercase:
--> 232             return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
    233         else:
    234             return strip_accents

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Please don't post text as image. Copy the traceback.

Comment: @kamlesh not sure yet but it might be linked with the datatype of df_all_null_removed[feature]. Is it a panda dataframe? can you provide more code, so I can run it on my machine? Make the dummy example as close as reality

Comment: Without a sample of your `observations`, it is highly unlikely that anyone here can help - please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, your `train_test_split` part should be removed, as it is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @maf88 thanks for your time and response . Yes 'df_all_null_removed' is a pandas data-frame.  And running about running on the local machine, you can use any categorical variables (more than 1) to run the above code snippet.

Comment: @MadPhysicist done

Answer (score 1):

You can use ColumnTransformer to have multiple different preprocessing pathways for your data.